# i want to change the admin panel favicon icon, how to do that?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I want to change the favicon icon of admin panel in magento. i have changed the favicon icon of the front end, but i want to change the admin panel's favicon icon also, how to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the admin default icon at

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 3):

Admin favicon icon path as below change the image

**skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico**